# Python web installer doesn't implement into cmd

Tags: python, windows

When I download Python from the web installer (https://www.python.org/downloads/), writing code into cmd doesn't work. However downloading it from the microsoft store does, anyone know why and how I can fix this?

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing one, then the other, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### see the python Get Started.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download

### For you to do the installation by cmd you must use:

For Red Hat, CentOS or Fedora, install the python3 and python3-devel packages.

For Debian or Ubuntu, install the python3.x and python3.x-dev packages.

exemple:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.x python3.x-dev
```

For Gentoo, install the '=python-3.x*' ebuild (you may have to unmask it first).

### To install on windows you must download

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.5/python-3.10.5-amd64.exe